# Backbone communication between views , a different pattern

Tags: events, backbone.js, mediator

I've read about mediator, event aggregator, using, backbone.events ...etc

I need advise about another potential pattern below, **do you think this is evil** ? or good ? if not good what are the caveats/problems.

This 'pattern' answers a very classical issue. When you click something on View1 , View2 has to render. View1 and View2 are independant (this is not a subview case). Between View1 and View2 we'll use an "Actions" module (yes more or less inspired by react/flux).

Here is the plan in pseudoCode:

```
View1:
     initialize:
        Actions.subscribe(this, 'view2);

View2:
     onclickwtv:
        Actions.displayView2();

Actions:
    this._Views = [];
    subscribe(view, viewName):
         this._Views[viewName] = view;

    displayView2:
         this._Views['view2'].render(); // or show or wtv function needed
```

When a view is removed we would call a unsubsribe function in actions that would pop the specific view off the _Views array.

The aim of this scheme is to have visibility on the different potential interactions between views (instead of an event aggregator where you don't have a central place to see those interactions).

Can't wait to read your thought about this!

Comment: Your question might be more appropriate for Code Review, http://codereview.stackexchange.com. That said, I think your solution has too much coupling. It would be better if Actions initialized the views and subscribed to them. The views can remain ignorant of Actions and can happily fire off events, blissfully unconcerned about who is listening.

Comment: Views are mostly initialized in router or sometimes in parent views

Comment: thanks for your feedback

Comment: It looks to me like your solution is trying to be a traditional Event Aggregator, but with more complexity. In a typical EA, the views would trigger and subscribe to events on the EA, but the EA need have no direct knowledge of the views. Your implementation puts control of the views into the EA, so the EA requires intimate knowledge of the views. This seems to me to be complexity that is neither necessary nor desirable.

Comment: what would you do to track the events more clearly ? btw you can post it as answer if you want more reputation points :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have View2 trigger an event on an Aggregator object:

```
onclickwtv: function () {
    Aggregator.trigger('wtc-click');
}
```

And I would have View1 subscribe to this event:

```
initialize: function () {
    this.listenTo(Aggregator, 'wtc-click', this.render);
}
```

Having View1 subscribe to Actions so that Actions can call View1.render() is just a roud-about way of achieving the same thing. Your solution has three decision-making objects, mine has only two. And my solution does not require management of the view states - a view will stop listening to the Aggregator when its `.remove()` method is called.

Comment: this is good. I was thinking about that yesterday. Also I was thinking about a shared model in singleton when views need to react together to some kind of data change what do you think ?

Comment: I once had a Filters view and a Pagination view, each with their own models. When the current filter changed, the current page needed to be set to 1. I achieved this by having a master model that owned the Filter model and the Pagination model as instances. This master model held the logic for listening to the Filter model and setting the Pagination model.